# Image not loading in ImageView that is created Dynamically

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to create a dynamic ImageView which downloads image from online server and loads in app. I am using code from this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/)

The problem is that code is working on static ImageView I created in layout file but not when I use it for dynamic ImageView. It loads loader image but does not replace with original image from URL after downloading to phone memory. It generates below error -

> D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false

Here is my ImageAdapter.java code -

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.pixelandpublish.shreeshasirestaurant.R;
import com.pixelandpublish.shreeshasirestaurant.activity.ProductsActivity;
import com.pixelandpublish.shreeshasirestaurant.model.Categories;

import java.util.List;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private DatabaseHandler db;

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        db = new DatabaseHandler(mContext);
        List<Categories> categories = db.getAllCategories();
        return categories.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(340, 340));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            imageView.setId(position);
        }
        else
        {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        //imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

        db = new DatabaseHandler(mContext);
        List<Categories> categories = db.getAllCategories();
        final String[] log = new String[categories.size()];
        final Integer[] id = new Integer[categories.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (Categories cn : categories) {
            log[i] = cn.getName();
            id[i] = cn.getID();

            i++;
        }

        // Loader image - will be shown before loading image
        int loader = R.drawable.ic;

        // Imageview to show
        //ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        // Image url
        String image_url = "http://api.androidhive.info/images/sample.jpg";

        // ImageLoader class instance
        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(mContext);

        // whenever you want to load an image from url
        // call DisplayImage function
        // url - image url to load
        // loader - loader image, will be displayed before getting image
        // image - ImageView
        imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, imageView);
        //imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(mContext, ProductsActivity.class);
                //Create the bundle
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

//Add your data to bundle
                bundle.putString("categoryId", String.valueOf(id[position]));

//Add the bundle to the intent
                i.putExtras(bundle);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mContext.getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
            }

        });

        return imageView;
    }

}
```

Thanx in advance. :)

Comment: you can simply use picasso library...http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-working-with-picasso--cms-22149

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4544091/4494555

Comment: @JacksonChengalai thanks mate.. now I am using picasso and its working fine.

Comment: i just posted it as answer please aceept .. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use picasso library for downloading images from internet...

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-working-with-picasso--cms-22149

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Univeral Image Loader for it...Refer this link 
[Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

```
  ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            ImageLoader.getInstance().init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(activity));
       DisplayImageOptions     options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.YOUR_DRWABLE)
                    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.YOUR_DRWABLE)
                    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.YOUR_DRWABLE)
                    .cacheInMemory(true)
                    .cacheOnDisk(true)
                    .considerExifParams(true)
                    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                    .build();


        imageLoader.DisplayImage("YOUR URL", R.drawable.YOUR_DRWABLE, IMAGEVIEW_HERE);
```